# Error inflating checkbox in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm having some issue with my pref_general.xml file as I get the following error message:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox

Then the logcat points the line in my PreferenceActivity where I call "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);"

After several hours of trying to sort it out I still have no idea what the issue is so maybe someone is familiar with this or simply another set of eyes can find the problem.

> **pref_general.xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="General">
    <!--  <SwitchPreference
        android:key="NOTIF"
        android:title="Activer ou dأ©sactiver les notifications" /> -->
    <CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="NOTIF"
    android:title="Activer/Désactiver les notifications" />

    <Preference
        android:key="cache"
        android:title="Vider le cache"/>


    <Preference
        android:key="FAQ"
        android:title="FAQ"
        android:summary="Questions fréquentes"
        />
    <Preference
        android:key="feedback"
        android:title="FeedBack"
        android:summary="S'il vous plaît envoyer nous un FeedBack"
        />
    <Preference
        android:key="version"
        android:title="Version"
        android:summary="1.0.0(Build A750)"
        />
    <Preference
        android:key="Copyright"
        android:title="Copyright"
        android:summary="Toutes les matières contenues sur ce site sont Protégées par Nextice Inc, droit d'auteur et ne peuvent pas étre reproduits, distribués, transmis, affichés, publiأés ou diffusés sans l'premission écrit préalable de la société Nextice."
        android:selectable="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        />

    </PreferenceCategory>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Also, i'm trying this in Android 5.1 everyting is fine, but in api 19 ( in my phone ) nothing working ?

> **SettingsActivity:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

CheckBoxPreference notification;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);


    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
    Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings, root, false);
    root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });



    SharedPreferences settingsPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    notification = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("NOTIF");
    notification.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("true"))
            {
                notificationsOn();
                //PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                //PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), null, MainActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_notification);

            }
            else
            {
                notificationsOff();
                //PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), null);
                //PushService.unsubscribe(getApplicationContext(), null);
                //PushService.unsubscribe(getApplicationContext(), "");
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void notificationsOn() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Notifications: Activée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().setNotificationEnabled(true);*/

        }

        private void notificationsOff() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Notifications: Desactivée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), null);
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().setNotificationEnabled(false);*/

        }

    });



    Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("feedback");
    myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", "feedback@soft-grip-support.esy.es", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Votre Sujet");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Votre FeedBack (Texte)");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Envoyer email à"));

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference ver =  (Preference) findPreference("version");
    ver.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

         Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "1.0.0(Build A750)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference cache =  (Preference) findPreference("cache");
    cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {


            deleteCache(SettingsActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Cache Vidée", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference faq = (Preference)findPreference("FAQ");
    faq.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

            String url = "www.soft-grip.net/faq";
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ActivityWebView.class);
            intent.putExtra("share", url);
            startActivity(intent);


            /*String url = "http://www.google.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);*/

            return false;
        }
    });

    Preference fb =  (Preference) findPreference("fb");
    fb.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/503359346436234"));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/Soft.Grip.Inc")));
            }

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference twt =  (Preference) findPreference("twt");
    twt.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            Intent intent = null;
            try {
                // get the Twitter app if possible
                getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=1588577185"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no Twitter app, revert to browser
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/SoftGripInc"));
            }
            startActivity(intent);

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference sms = (Preference)findPreference("sms");
    sms.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

            Intent sendIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "smsBody");
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

            return false;
        }
    });

    Preference http =  (Preference) findPreference("http");
    http.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            String url = "http://www.soft-grip.net";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

            return false;

        }
    });

    Preference merci =  (Preference) findPreference("deve");
    merci.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            ShowDialog(SettingsActivity.this, "Merci", "Merci d'utiliser l'App Soft Grip!\nDéveloppeur : Soft Grip Inc. \nTous les droits réservés. \nSoft-Grip Inc © 2015 ", false);
            return false;

        }




        public void ShowDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(null);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon
//  alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}
    });


}

public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

> **Logcat:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:701)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:531)
    at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:494)
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:222)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2351)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1816)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2207)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1677)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1445)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5998)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
    at com.android.into
```

Comment: What was the reason for downvoting this question?

Comment: did you trunc a line or just forgot to close PreferenceScreen tag?

Comment: @PabloRivero nop i'm not forgot to close it 
just cut some lines to post the code here :/ 
Than you

Comment: I gonna make a shot in the dark, but it might be because of the backslash in the string Activer/Désactiver les notifications . try to change the text and let me know.

Comment: @UrielFrankel i don't think so cause i added another activity and xml pref with CheckBoxPreference with a simple text nothing working and the same problem but when i delet this CheckBoxPreference everything work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817) in version `23.2.0` of the support library that can cause this.

This was fixed in revision `23.2.1` of the library. This revision states the following which I believe was the root cause of the issue and explains why it only failed on your phone running API 19:

> Fixed an exception in DrawableCompat.wrap() and LayerDrawable on API
>   levels 17 to 19.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, have you tried removing the "/" character from

```
android:title="Activer/Désactiver les notifications"
```

Edit: I should have probably made this a comment, but I don't have the reputation (yet.)

Comment: it's not with "/" it's about the support library 23.2.0 it' was a bug to run app in Api 19 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!