# Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, android-preferences

Please Help, i'm having some issue with my pref_general.xml file whene i'm luanching the SettingsActivity ( PreferenceActivity ) as the app spotted and i get the following error message:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox

Then the logcat points the line in my PreferenceActivity where I call "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);"

After several hours of trying to sort it out I still have no idea what the issue is so maybe someone is familiar with this or simply another set of eyes can find the problem.

Also, i'm trying this in Android 5.1 everyting is fine, but in Android Api 19 ( in my phone ) nothing working ?

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:676)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:701)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:531)
at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:494)
at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:222)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2351)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1816)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2207)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1445)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5998)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
at com.android.int
```

Thanks all =D

Comment: Can you add the xml files?

Comment: @PabloRivero Check this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553818/error-inflating-checkbox-in-preferenceactivity)  and please, Thank you :/

Comment: Are you sure this is the full stack trace from logcat? It looks cut off at the end. `at com.android.into`

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan it's `at com.android.int` not `at com.android.into`
just a mistake 
and i'm sure :/

Comment: Please show your pref_general.xml file that's being inflated.

Comment: @DougStevenson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553818/error-inflating-checkbox-in-preferenceactivity
This is mine

Comment: Are you using the support libraries? If so what version? Only asking because I had similar issues with version 23.2.0 and those issues were since fixed in later versions. However, the stack trace was a bit different so it is most likely unrelated.

Comment: i think it's a version cause i'm launching the app in Api 21 everything is fine, but when i launch it in Api less than Api 21 didn't work (just launching   settingsActivity) so why ? befor it was working for all android Apis

Comment: What version of the support libraries are you using though? There was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817) in the support library that only affected certain API levels and that could potentially explain it.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`

Comment: That is the version with the issue. increment all the support library versions to the latest (23.3.0) or at least (23.2.1) and let me know if it fixes it. If it does I'll post an answer with the related notes on this.

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna updated it now, Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108858/discussion-between-mohamed-chergui-and-george-mulligan).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817) in version `23.2.0` of the support library that can cause this.

This was fixed in revision `23.2.1` of the library. This revision states the following which I believe was the root cause of the issue and explains why it only failed on your phone running API 19:

> Fixed an exception in DrawableCompat.wrap() and LayerDrawable on API
>   levels 17 to 19.

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me :)